# Show a DB as a directory (Like Sharepoint Does)

Tags: file, storage, webdav

My team and I are programming a sort of Document Manager and the idea is to store them completely on DB. 
Is there a protocol or Extensions that allows us to show a "Virtual Directory" or files that are really non existent (only in DB). How does Sharepoint do this? 
I understand that Sharepoint uses WebDav but it implies that the files do exist physically somewhere.

We intend to develop this application on .NET 4.0 and deploy it on IIS.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Interwoven Teamsite also exposes its content repository as a drive that can be shared over the network. It is a bit pricey for doing just that, though. But you could certainly build a .Net app that integrates with it.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that Sharepoint uses WebDav but it implies that the files do exist physically somewhere.

No, WebDAV doesn't imply that; it's simply a wire protocol; you can store the content any way you like.